# Scale a table to fit browser window, but keep proportions

Tags: html, css, scaling, css-tables

I'm making a chessboard using only html and css. The chessboard is inside a table. I'm able to scale the table to fit the browser window and at the same time keep the proportions of a square using css:

```
table {

    position: fixed;
    height: 0%;
    width: 90%;
    padding-bottom: 80%;

}
```

But whats bothering me is that the table-body (whith rows, columns and header) only change its width, not height. I have tried so many different approaches with positioning, width, height, padding, and i'm not able to figure this one out.

Any suggestions or solutions to this problem?

Comment: you have a fixed postion, you can use top, bottom, left and right to reach your aim.

Comment: Could you please post the complete code?

Comment: use grids [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)